# Get product details by product id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, class

Hi i have a **product id 22** . I want to get the product details by this id . in this page

> default/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/Products.phtml

**Example** :

```
$product=get_product_details(22);
```

I want to create an object `$products using this id so i can call the built in functions like

```
$product->getProductUrl()
$product->getName()
```

Is there any built in function available ?

Comment: You are using custom file Products.phtml to display products?

Comment: I will suggest you to use view model for this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Object manager method:

```
$product_id = "Your Product Id";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

> Factory Method

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

You can load product data by adding below content to your phtml file.

```
$product = $block->getLoadProduct(22);
echo $product->getName();
echo $product->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to get the product using product id

```
$product_id=22;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try with below id get product details using below code :

```
$product_id=22;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

than try with below code

```
$product->getData();
```

than getting response

if you want **short_description** than use `$product->getShortDescription()` for all you can use which are listed in `getData()`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using ObjectManager is not recommended. I would suggest you to use block class or create a view Model and define your methods there. That way your code will follow the best practices